# Arguments with regex

Tags: php, regex

I would like to know how to split this string:
command arg1 arg2 arg3
In this array:

```
[arg1,arg2,arg3]
```

BUT if the user types:
command "arg1 still arg1" arg2
The array will be:

```
[arg1 still arg1, arg2]
```

Using PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP does what you ask automatically.

I have PHP 5.3, and calling this code

```
<?php
  print $argc . "\n";

  for ($i = 0; $i < $argc; $i++) {
    print $argv[$i] . "\n";
  }
?>
```

with `php ./argv.php Test "Test 23" "Test 34"`, I obtain the following output

```
sunradio:~ kiamlaluno$ php ./argv.php Test "Test 23" "Test 34"
4
./argv.php
Test
Test 23
Test 34
sunradio:~ kiamlaluno$
```

Taking off the first argument, `$argv` contains all the arguments as you want them. That can be easily done with `array_pop()`.

Comment: I changed the code to use `$argc` (I use those variables very rarely, that I always forget about `$argc`).
I interpreted that you meant to parse the arguments passed to PHP when executed from CLI.

Answer (score 2):

Use a regular expression like this:

```
^[^ ]+(?: ("[^"]+"|[^ ]+))*$
```

The expression `"[^"]+"|[^ ]+` matches either an argument that starts and ends with a quotation mark, or an argument that ends at the next space.

Comment: This doesn't work, I am using preg_split('^[^ ]+(?: ("[^"]+"|[^ ]+))*$',$text);

Comment: Error message: Unknown modifier ']'

Comment: If you're using a Perl compatible regex for `preg_replace` you need to surround the regex with delimiters, such as //

Comment: iirc all `preg_` functions require the regex to be delimited - wrap the regex in `/` marks or some other delimiter.

Comment: Code:
echo 1 2 3
Result:
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => 
)

Comment: Read the definition of `preg_replace` in the online documentation: http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: I don't want to use preg_replace, I want to use preg_split.

Comment: Or preg_split (as the case may be). I'm thinking of the description of the parameter which contains a perl regular expression.

Comment: I am using:

$params=preg_split('/^[^ ]+(?: ("[^"]+"|[^ ]+))*$/',$full);

But print_r($params); returns:

Array

(

    [0] => 

    [1] => 

)

Comment: I have tested it in Rad Software Regular Expression Designer, and it works just fine. The first group contains captures for all the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I believe  you might want to use something like strtok for this in php, rather than a regex.

See this comment on the documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php#94463